# How to convert row names to column names and bind it by order in r

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns, spread

I am working on a data set:
[Annual Returns by Ticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1aqZ.png)

and I want to convert to : [Result Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRPWS.png)

I used the code:

returns.df <- returns %>% spread(key = DATE, value = RETURN)

and its is showing wrong order: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNEVn.png)

Comment: Just want to check: your complaint is the order of the columns in the result?

Comment: Images do not provide a reproducible way to run the code. Please provide a reproducible example, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your long-form data starts with the rows in the order you want, try this:

```
month_order = unique(returns)
returns.df <- returns %>%
  spread(key = DATE, value = RETURN) %>% 
  select(c("TICKER", month_order))
```

If your data doesn't begin in the right order, append a year and convert it to a `Date` class object. Then you can sort it to the right order and use the method above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my writing these multiple lines:

```
column <- unique(returns$DATE)
ret <- matrix(returns$RETURN,nrow = 22,ncol = 60)
row <- unique(returns$TICKER)
rownames(ret) <- row
colnames(ret) <- column
ret
```

How about this one?